# Django form save via jQuery Ajax POST request when I m submit the URL I m redirect to main form page to JSON response page

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-forms

**I'm using  Django form and save via jQuery ajax post request.**

**When submit the form I don't know why redirect to JSON response page and also  I don't know why I m not getting response on same page in success:funcation**

**urls.**

```
path("iEasy/Group-Type/Add/form/masterside/", views.Add_GrpPage, name="add_grp_page_m"),
```

**View.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def Add_Handle_M(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                form = HandleMaster_Form(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid:
                    forms = form.save(commit=False)
                    forms.create_by = request.user
                    #forms.save()
                    msg_error=messages.success(request,"Added")
            except:
                msg_error=messages.error(request,str(form.errors))
    return JsonResponse({'msg_error':msg_error})
```

**Html File**

```
<form id="handle_add_form" action="{% url 'add_handle_m' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{Handle_Form}}
          <div class="mt-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>  
        </form>
```

**jQuery AJAX **

```
  var add_handle_m = $('#add_handle_m');
  add_handle_m.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      type:montadd_handle_mh_add_form.attr('method'),
      url:add_handle_m.attr('action'),
      data:  serializedData,
      success: function(data, status){
        if (status)
        {
          alert("Added")
          location.reload(true)
        }
        else{
          alert(data.data)
        } 
        
      },

    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, your form id is `id="handle_add_form"`.But, in jquery code you have added `add_handle_m`.